# How to call service from ag-grid valueFormatter

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

Does anyone know how to call service from ValueFormatter of ag-grid in Angular2+?

Example:

I have injected a service called someService in the constructor and would like to call the service from the ValueFormatter. What should i do to achieve that?

```
constructor(private service: SomeService) { }

this.columnDefs.push(
        {
            headerName: 'Date',
            width: 150,
            field: 'incidentDate',
            valueFormatter(params) {
                return this.service.doSomething(params.value);
            }
        });
```

At the moment, it doesn't recognise the service from the valueFormatter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `return this.service.doSomething(params.value);` it means that you use `this` as a reference to the ag-grid component, it is not a reference to your hosted component. Therefore, you need to encapculate logic with a new private function inside your component and there you should use `this` to reference your hosted component and its injected service.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. I simply need to do the following:

```
 this.columnDefs.push(
    {
        headerName: 'Date',
        width: 150,
        field: 'incidentDate',
        valueFormatter: this.anotherFunction.bind(this)
    });

anotherFunction(params): string {
    return this.service.doSomething(params.value);
}
```

Comment: As you spotted, the `this` is not your component. An alternative is: `valueFormatter: (params) => this.anotherFunction(params)`.

Comment: @GruffBunny You are my hero. The bind looked so ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the reference of `someService` instance created from the constructor. Which can be fixed by having `this` keyword. Try the code below

```
valueFormatter(params) {
   return this.service.doSomething(params.value);
}
```

Comment: That was a typo from my end. I forgot to put this. But even with this, it still does not work. have you used ag-grid before?